# ClassLoader with Sandbox reports StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, security, classloader, sandbox

I'm using [de.unkrig.commons.lang.security.Sandbox.confine](http://commons.unkrig.de/javadoc/commons-lang/index.html) to solve Java Security issue [Download of Code Without Integrity Check](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/494.html).

Below is the findClass method in my custom classloader extends from ClassLoader.

With this implementation, it reports a StackOverFlowError.

Anyone knows what happened to this? And how to solve it?

Many thanks!

```
@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> cls;
    try {
        cls = super.findClass(name);
        Sandbox.confine(cls, getPermissions());
        return cls;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        for (ClassLoader delegate : _delegateClassLoaders) {
            try {
                 cls = delegate.loadClass(name);
                if (cls != null) {
                    Sandbox.confine(cls, getPermissions());
                    return cls;
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException fe) {
            }
        }
    }
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
}

protected Permissions getPermissions() {
    Permissions pm = new Permissions();
    FilePermission p = new FilePermission("/tmp/*", "read,write");
    pm.add(p);
    return pm;
}
```

Comment: never catch an exception and do not handle it `} catch (ClassNotFoundException fe) {
            }
`

Answer (score -1):

(wanted to comment but I'm new here and don't have enough rep)

First, you are calling `super.findClass()` while you are extending `ClassLoader` - it will always throw a `ClassNotFoundException` :

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
}
```

Second I don't know this Sandbox library, but you probably have an infinite recursion here. Note that `loadClass()` calls `findClass()` in the default `ClassLoader` implementation;

Might it be that one of the delegates is the same class running this code? did you try to debug it?